# Forcing Ale to display Perl::Critic violations as warnings rather than errors

Tags: perl, vim, perl-critic

I'm using `vim` with the `Ale` plugin.  By default, `perlcritic` violations show up as errors.  I'd like to see them displayed as warnings. According to `:help g:ale_type_map` I should be able to do this, but it isn't clear to me exactly how.

`let g:ale_type_map = {'perl': {'E': 'W'}}` will change `perl` errors into warnings.

`let g:ale_type_map = {'perl': {'ES': 'WS'}}` does not appear to have any effect on the critic violations.  Neither do either of these:

```
let g:ale_type_map = {'perlcritic': {'ES': 'WS', 'E': 'W'}}
let g:ale_type_map = {'perl_perlcritic': {'ES': 'WS', 'E': 'W'}}
```

The docs on this are pretty sparse, so I'm unclear on whether it's an issue with syntax, linter name or something else entirely.

Comment: You should try the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I actually did this in tandem with an open GitHub issue.  Turns out it's partly down to my error and partly down to an issue with Ale that could be improved.  I'll answer my own question shortly.  :)

Comment: Plagiarised here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1198801

Comment: Wow. What a weird thing to plagiarize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hearing from the author, this is the correct syntax, which allows you to set options for both `perltidy` and `Perl::Critic`:

```
let g:ale_type_map = {
\    'perl': {'ES': 'WS'}, 
\    'perlcritic': {'ES': 'WS', 'E': 'W'},
\}
```

My issue was that my simple test case was picking up a `perl` warning as well as a `Perl::Critic` violation.  The gutter was showing the `perl` warning as an error, but the bottom of the pane was displaying the `Perl::Critic` violation, which was pretty confusing.  After getting rid of the warning, I was able to see `Perl::Critic` violations as warnings. There is an already open issue to deal with this in `Ale`, but I thought it would be helpful to post the answer here for anyone else with questions.

The main takeaway is that `ale_type_map` is a dict, so if you try to set it more than once, the last entry will win.  The syntax above is what you want if you'd like to deal with multiple linters.